# Javascript Remove data from array function

Tags: javascript

I have an array and here's how it looks:

```
{id:"1", videotype:"youtube", videoId:"y685gVGRQ98"},{id:"2", videotype:"youtube", videoId:"CtjuDJytD18"}
```

Each entry has an Id.

I need a function to remove all entries belonging to the chosen Id.

for example:

```
removeFromArray(2);

It would then remove all this: id:"2", videotype:"youtube", videoId:"CtjuDJytD18"
```

Comment: Are you talking about `.splice()` ? __unclear what you're asking__

Comment: How have you not found out about splice when searching for this?

Comment: Why the downvote....Have you got nothing better to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Reworded the whole question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is...How do I do to remove a specific entry?

You can write another method

```
removeDataToArray: function(id, videotype, videoId) {
       var videoArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("videoLinksArray").innerHTML);
       //filter out item that matches the id, videoType and videoId
       videoArray = videoArray.filter( function(val){
          return !( val.id == id && val.videoType == videoType && val.videoId == videoId );
       });
       document.getElementById("videoLinksArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( videoArray );
},
```

> It would be more like: removeDataFromArray(id) and it would know the
>   unique id of the entry

Then the filter will change to

```
       videoArray = videoArray.filter( function(val){
          return val.id != id;
       });
```

**Edit**

> `removeFromArray(2);`
>
> It would then remove all this: id:"2", videotype:"youtube",
>   videoId:"CtjuDJytD18"

```
removeDataToArray: function(id) {
       var videoArray = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("videoLinksArray").innerHTML);
       //filter out item that match the id
       videoArray = videoArray.filter( function(val){
          return val.id != String( id ) ;
       });
       document.getElementById("videoLinksArray").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( videoArray );
},
```

Comment: @overburn that is if you already know the index. For knowing the index you still need to iterate the array.

Comment: @Satch3000 Okay, added the changes for that as well.

Comment: You need to convert it to String before comparison.

Comment: @Satch3000 check now

Comment: @Satch3000 can you share the output of `document.getElementById("videoLinksArray").innerHTML` ? Looks like it is not a valid JSON

Comment: @Satch3000 this is not a valid JSON. It needs to be surrounded by `[` and `]`

Comment: @Satch3000 how are you making this JSON array?

Comment: @Satch3000 Rather than constructing the JSON String, populate the object. like `var vdoData = {
 id : id,
 videotype : videotype,
 videoId : videoId
}` Add this to array as `videoArray.push(vdoData)`

Comment: @Satch3000 yes, you need to `JSON.stringify(array)` before setting to innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

Modified for the updated question:

```
blacklistedId = 1;

newArray = oldArray.filter(function(value) {
    return value.id != blacklistedId;
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to delete single elements. I've changed the question, please have a read if you don't mind, thanks.

Comment: It ended up being the same as the other answer though :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider using utility library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#reject):

```
var desired_list = removeFromList([{id:"1", videotype:"youtube", videoId:"y685gVGRQ98"},{id:"2", videotype:"youtube", videoId:"CtjuDJytD18"}], "1");

function removeFromList(list, id) {
   return _.reject(list, function(val){return val.id == id});
}
```

enjoy